# Ajax double forms, first form with select then classic form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

So I have one form in frontend. And second form in process file.
With first form i calling second form with products information.

FIRST FORM

```
      $izmena_proizvoda = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM proizvodi");
      $izmena_proizvoda->execute();
      echo '<form method="POST">';
      echo '<select class="form-control" name="izmena_proizvoda" id="izaberi_proizvod" onchange="izmena_proizvoda_ajax(this.value);">';
      echo '<option>Izaberite proizvod</option>';
            while($izmena_proizvoda_o=$izmena_proizvoda->fetch()){
                echo '<option value="'.$izmena_proizvoda_o['id_sata'].'">';
                echo $izmena_proizvoda_o['nazivsata'];
                echo '</option>';
            }
      echo '</select>';
      echo '</form>';
```

And ajax for this form

```
    function izmena_proizvoda_ajax(val){
    $.ajax({
        url: "../sadrzaj/stranice/izmenaproizvoda.php",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            izmena_proizvoda:val
        },
        success: function (response) {
            document.getElementById("izmena_proizvoda_prikaz").innerHTML = response;
            console.log(response)

        }
    });
}
```

In process file i have this one.

```
if(isset($_POST['izmena_proizvoda'])){
$izmena_proizvoda_forma = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM proizvodi WHERE id_sata = :id_sata");
$izmena_proizvoda_forma->bindParam(':id_sata', $_POST['izmena_proizvoda'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$izmena_proizvoda_forma->execute();
echo '<hr>';
echo '<form method="post" action="#" id="izmena_proizvoda_update_form" class="ajax" >';
while($izmena_proizvoda_forma_o=$izmena_proizvoda_forma->fetch()){
    echo'        
              <input type="hidden" name="slika_za_brisanje" value="'.$izmena_proizvoda_forma_o['slika'].'">       
              <input type="hidden" name="id_izmena" value="'.$izmena_proizvoda_forma_o['id_sata'].'">
              <label for="naslov_izmena">Naziv sata</label>
              <input type="text" id="naslov_izmena" name="naslov_izmena" class="form-control" value="'.$izmena_proizvoda_forma_o['nazivsata'].'">
              <label for="cena_izmena">Cena</label>
              <input id="cena_izmena" type="text" name="cena_izmena" class="form-control" value="'.$izmena_proizvoda_forma_o['cenasata'].'"><br>
              <label for="vodootpornost">Vodootpornost</label>
              <input id="vodootpornost" type="text" name="vodootpornost" class="form-control" value="'.$izmena_proizvoda_forma_o['vodootpornost'].'"><br>
              <label for="zalihe">Zalihe</label>
              <input id="zalihe" type="text" name="zalihe" class="form-control" value="'.$izmena_proizvoda_forma_o['zalihe'].'"><br>
              <label for="pol">Pol sata</label>
              <input id="pol" type="text" name="pol" class="form-control" value="'.$izmena_proizvoda_forma_o['pol'].'"><br>
              <label for="opissata_izmena"></label>';
    echo '  <textarea id="opissata_izmena" rows="10" name="opissata_izmena">'.$izmena_proizvoda_forma_o['opissata'].'</textarea><br>';

    echo '<input type="submit" name="izmena_proizvoda_potvrda" value="Sacuvaj izmene" class="btn btn-info">';
}
echo '</form>';
}
```

So when i do that on frontend. works fine. But when i try to do another ajax for form2 i have a problems. I dont know how i can run a ajax for another form. 
I try to put ajax code in forntend page but didnt work. Also i tryed to put ajax in process file below the form. To call both together. also didnt fork.
How I can make some trigger for ajax 2 from ajax 1 like

Ajax1: Hey ajax2 i do my job. You now have a form. When user click submit, do your job and dont refres a page.

Sorry beacuse my bad english.

Comment: Try adding `onclick="mySecondAjaxFunction()"` to the submit button on your second form (I advise you not to use the `<form>` tag) and copy your AJAX2 inside a function called `mySecondAjaxFunction()` (or whatever you'd like it to be called). That should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get rid of your `onchange` handler, keep your `<form>` tags and attach your event handler to all forms instead of a specific form. Then use `$(this)` to reference the values of the form which generates the submission event.

```
$("form").on("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var data = $(this).serialize(); // Grabs all data from the form being submitted
  $.ajax({
    url: "../sadrzaj/stranice/izmenaproizvoda.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    success: function(response) {
      document.getElementById("izmena_proizvoda_prikaz").innerHTML = response;
      console.log(response);
      // If you need to alter success handlers you can add data elements to your form HTML and reference them here
      // Same is true if you need to alter submission URL or whatever
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need other way to assign the event to your new HTML elements.
This way assign an event to any dynamic HTML element.

```
$(function() {

  //Assign event to input submit with name izmena_proizvoda_potvrda
  $(document).on('click', 'input[name=izmena_proizvoda_potvrda]',
    function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      //Ajax request

    }); //end function()

})
```